# photolibrary and mediaanalysis daemons causing excessive CPU loads

Tags: macos, cpu

I just upgraded my iMac 2016 to MacOS 13 and it is currently unusable (i.e. the UI is mostly unresponsive). Remotely logging in via ssh I see that the photolibrary and mediaanalysis daemons are consuming all the CPU:

[image]

Is this a common problem? Do I need to just wait them out? Can I turn these off?

Comment: Does your Mac have an SSD or spinning HDD? This all might be totally normal and letting it not sleep overnight will resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: [from what I can see](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/index-imac.html), there wasn't a 2016 iMac: there were 2015 iMacs and 2017 iMacs. The 2015 iMacs are only supported up to Monterey (OS 12). ([Ventura](https://support.apple.com/HT213264) supported iMacs start with the 2017 models.)

After a new OS install, it's likely that there will be a fair amount of background 'churn': Spotlight indexing, Time Machine backups, and processing of photos and other data for new features.

However, note that the % CPU value is per core, and your CPU will have several cores. With 4 cores, 48% of one core is 12% of the total CPU.

So it's possible that the sluggishness isn't CPU being maxed out; but rather something else. It's possible that some software you've got on there isn't compatible with Ventura, and needs updating, or removing. Also, if you've got a mechanical hard drive in there, it's not going to be fast, and the drive is old, and may be failing.

Comment: Yeah it is  a Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015. Also, I upgraded to MacOS 12 (not 13). Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: It turns out is was most about 24 hours of churn. I have a massive number of images and video for my work -- I think it spent all its resources indexing them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no iMac 2016 - but the 2015 & 2017 are notoriously slow anyway [sorry]. The 2015 can't run Ventura, so let's assume the 2017.

The figures you see are 'percentage of one core' not of the entire machine, but as you only have 4 cores, 2 of which are not 'real' [hyperthreading cores] plus those operations are going to be reading & writing to disk a lot, I can imagine it will cause slowdown.

It's a task that really you should let complete, so I'd leave the Mac on [and awake] overnight & see how it's going in the morning.

Comment: I was running a (much) older OS version (Catalina) and the machine ran smoothly. You're right -- not 2016 --  iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015). I'll restart and then let it run for a day ... This is not a matter of slowness -- I am talking unusable. It has 32GB ram FWIW